# Why is my Node.js INSERT giving me a Rethrow non-MySQL errors, Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: you have an error in your MySQL syntax?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express

All I'm trying to do is INSERT the values from post into my user table. This has worked before but now I'm getting the error in the title. Any help would be appreciated.

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var db = require('../helpers/db');
var empty = require('is-empty');
var Password = require('node-php-password');

router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
  var firstName = req.body.first;
  var lastName = req.body.last;
  var username = req.body.username;
  var password = req.body.password;
  var permission = 2;

  db.query('SELECT username FROM user WHERE username = ?', [username], function (err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    if (!empty(result)) {
      console.log('Taken');
    } else {
      var hash = Password.hash(password, "PASSWORD_DEFAULT");
      var post = {
          first: firstName,
          last: lastName,
          username: username,
          password: hash,
          permission: permission
      };
      db.query('INSERT INTO user SET = ?', post, function (err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('ok');
      });
    }
    res.redirect('/');
  });

});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: INSERT INTO user SET is invalid.  The SET operator is for updates only.  INSERT INTO user ( first, last, password, permission) values ... is correct syntax for inserts.  It depends entirely on table structure as to mandatory vs nullable columns as to which columns you want to insert into.  You can't set a row based on an array.  You must specify the values individually.  "post" has no meaning to a database.

Comment: I literally use the same code with different variables in order to INSERT information about uploaded images to my database so that is definitely not the case.

Here's the db query that works just fine: 

db.query('INSERT INTO image SET ?', post, function (err, result) {
          if (err) throw err;
        });